# Error installing ruby-2.0.0-p353 using RVM

Tags: ruby, osx-mavericks, libyaml

I am trying to install and set up my dev environment for RoR, on a Mac OSX Maverick 10.9. 
After run the command:

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p353
```

the following error out:

```
Installing required packages: libyaml, openssl.
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install libyaml openssl',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/wlinares/.rvm/log/1388963243_ruby-2.0.0-p353/package_install_libyaml_openssl.log
        esac;
        return $ret
    }
}
```

I downloaded `libyaml` from http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/  and installed following the default instructions.

Then I made the same for openssl so it was installed successfully under: `/usr/lib/`

Anyone has overcome this error? thanks!

Comment: Got the latest version of XCode on there?

Comment: Try `brew update` then try rvm install

Comment: Yes I did both things, I have Xcode 5 and tools previously installed. After I exec brew update but not update was found I have the last one. About rvm I have already installed it and the version is: rvm 1.25.14 (stable).  I can't get rid off this error yet.

Comment: you need to install not a binaries, but headers, which is usually resided in devel packages.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0-p353 --autolibs=enable
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying many tricks I could not overcome the issue, then I uninstalled everything and restart the process as a beginner I am. I decided to run the command.

$ gem install rails

then I installed gems:

$  gem install rubygems-update

and finally tested the environment with: rails new blog command.

Until here all seems to be working fine, but I am following the ruby guides in order to start coding my project. I don't have RVM now so I don't know how to handle with upgrades and versions.
That is my only problem, because I was told that Rails change frequently. 
I would like to know now how to handle with upgrades including gems.